# Is there a way to determine viability of Infopath Fields based on a Sharepoint list?

Tags: list, infopath

The idea is, to have a form in which only certain users can see one field.

We would have a locked down list that held the UserID's of those who can see the field, and the form would look that up. So if your ID is in the table, you can see this text field.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can very well achieve this functionality. All you have to do is create a list which will contains the required user's emails. Then you will have a data connection to this list.

You can add a hidden text box inside infopath form and with help of getuserprofilebyname web service you can get current user's email id. The hidden text box will have the user email id only if user belongs to that list.

Then you can write condtional rule on display properties of text field-
rule- if HiddenTextBox value is blank, hide this textbox.

Conclusion if user belongs to this list then he can see the field otherwise he will not.

Let me know if u need further inputs.

Comment: I was able to pull the information from the list, that was very helpful, but how do I check that list of names against the textbox with the userID? I've tried using a conditional, but it only checks against the first item. Any suggestions?

Comment: u can write the rule like this-HiddenTextFieldVaue equals to @Member[. = Value[Name = "WorkEmail"]]
where @Member is the column name in the list which contains the email id of the user.

N.B.- hiddenfield value will be blank if user is not present in the list and value will not be blank if user is present.

Sorry for the late reply....